# Grouping a 2x2 set of options

Tags: selection, options

I'm am not sure what kind of grouping to use to present the following four options:

- Block something permanently
- Allow something permanently
- Block something once
- Allow something once

Initially I had grouped them by block vs allow. Now I'm thinking about grouping them by permanent vs once.

Do you have suggestions for a good solution here as I am unable to find best practices or similar for this.

Sorry, maybe "grouping" is the wrong word here. I rather mean the order of options.

Thank you

Comment: Do those need to be grouped? You are introducing two extra terms (group names) to your users for just four options.

Comment: Just updated my question: The word grouping was not correctly used here. I'm more talking about the order of the options which will stand side by side like: <br> A - B - - - C - D (at least at this point)<br> So: All options are side by side, just visually 'grouped' by some whitespace in the middle. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you probably know is that you want to allow or deny something. So the first choice to make is to allow or to deny it, followed by the choice if that is permanently or just for once:

Think of it as a conversation:

> Do you want to allow or deny it?
>   And do you want that permanently or this time only?

Makes more sense than:

> Do you want it permanently or one time only?
>   And do you want to allow or deny it?

Grouping it this way would make more sense if you follow this principle:

Allow:
- Permanently
- One-off

Deny:
- Permanently
- One-off